# One Class Classifier for balanced binary dataset

Tags: classification, binary-data, one-class

Can I use one class classifier for the balanced binary dataset?

For example, consider a text sentiment analysis dataset in which a number of positive and negative samples are equal

Can I use one class classifier for this example? If not why can't I use one-class classifier for balanced dataset

What are the properties of a one-class classifier?

Can anybody please provide the reference of one-class classifier base paper

Comment: What do you mean by "one class classifier"?

Comment: we train the model with only single class and test on binary class data

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification

Comment: If you have binary, balanced data, you want a binary classifier. What would you use one-class classifier if you have two-class data?

Comment: To improve the model I'm thinking to do one class classification for binary data? My question is that doing one-class classification for balanced binary data is correct or not theoretically

Comment: How would using one-class classifier improve binary classifier?

Comment: Practically somehow Im improving but I would like to know is it theorically acceptable or not